# Dilogarithm integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s/2-1}}{1+x^s} \text{Li}_2(-x) dx=- \frac{\pi^3}{4} \left( \frac1{3 s}+ \frac1{ s^3}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\mathbb{R} \ni s \geq 2$. Prove that:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s/2-1}}{1+x^s} \text{Li}_2(-x) dx=- \frac{\pi^3}{4} \left( \frac1{3 s}+ \frac1{ s^3}\right)$$

---

My proof (Some shorter test?)
$\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}\cdot Li_{2}\left( -x \right)dx}\underbrace{=}_{x=\frac{1}{y}}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\left( \frac{1}{y} \right)^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+\frac{1}{y^{s}}}\cdot Li_{2}\left( -\frac{1}{y} \right)\frac{dy}{y^{2}}}=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{y^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+y^{s}}\cdot Li_{2}\left( -\frac{1}{y} \right)dy}$

$=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}\cdot \left( Li_{2}\left( -x \right)+Li_{2}\left( -\frac{1}{x} \right) \right)dx}=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}\cdot \left( -\frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}-\frac{1}{2}\ln ^{2}x \right)dx}$

$=-\frac{\pi ^{2}}{12}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}dx}-\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}\ln ^{2}xdx}$

$\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}dx}\underbrace{=}_{x=u^{\frac{1}{s}}}\frac{1}{s}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\left( u^{\frac{1}{s}} \right)^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+u}u^{\frac{1}{s}-1}du}=\frac{1}{s}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{u^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{1+u}du}=\frac{1}{s}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{u^{\frac{1}{2}-1}}{\left( 1+u \right)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}}du}=\frac{1}{s}\beta \left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)=\frac{\pi }{s}$

$\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}\ln ^{2}xdx}\underbrace{=}_{x=u^{\frac{1}{s}}}\frac{1}{s}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{\left( u^{\frac{1}{s}} \right)^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+u}\left( \frac{1}{s}\ln u \right)^{2}u^{\frac{1}{s}-1}du}=\frac{1}{s^{3}}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{u^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{s}}\cdot u^{\frac{1}{s}-1}}{1+u}\ln ^{2}udu}$

$=\frac{1}{s^{3}}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{u^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{1+u}\ln ^{2}udu}\underbrace{=}_{u=\frac{t}{1-t}}\frac{1}{s^{3}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\left( \frac{t}{1-t} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{1+\frac{t}{1-t}}\left( \ln \frac{t}{1-t} \right)^{2}\frac{dt}{\left( 1-t \right)^{2}}}$

$=\frac{1}{s^{3}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left( 1-t \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left( \ln ^{2}t-2\ln t\ln \left( 1-t \right)+\ln ^{2}\left( 1-t \right) \right)dt}$

Note that $\beta \left( x,y \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{t^{x-1}\left( 1-t \right)^{y-1}dt}$
$\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\beta \left( x,y \right)=\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{t^{x-1}\left( 1-t \right)^{y-1}dt}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{t^{x-1}\left( 1-t \right)^{y-1}\ln ^{2}tdt}$

$=\left( \left( \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( x \right)-\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( x+y \right) \right)^{2}+\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( x \right)-\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( x+y \right) \right)\beta \left( x,y \right)$

analogously
$\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}\beta \left( x,y \right)=\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{t^{x-1}\left( 1-t \right)^{y-1}dt}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{t^{x-1}\left( 1-t \right)^{y-1}\ln ^{2}\left( 1-t \right)dt}$

$=\left( \left( \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( y \right)-\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( x+y \right) \right)^{2}+\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( y \right)-\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( x+y \right) \right)\beta \left( x,y \right)$

and
$\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial y\partial x}\beta \left( x,y \right)=\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial y\partial x}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{t^{x-1}\left( 1-t \right)^{y-1}dt}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{t^{x-1}\left( 1-t \right)^{y-1}\ln t\ln \left( 1-t \right)dt}$

$=\left( \left( \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( x \right)-\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( x+y \right) \right)\left( \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( y \right)-\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( x+y \right) \right)-\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( x+y \right) \right)\beta \left( x,y \right)$

then
$\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}\ln ^{2}xdx}=\frac{1}{s^{3}}\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\beta \left( x,y \right)\left| _{\left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)} \right.+\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}\beta \left( x,y \right)\left| _{\left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)} \right.-\frac{2\partial ^{2}}{\partial y\partial x}\beta \left( x,y \right)\left| _{\left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)} \right. \right)$

$=\frac{1}{s^{3}}\left( 2\left( \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)-\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( 1 \right) \right)^{2}+2\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)-2\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( 1 \right)+2\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( 1 \right)-2\left( \psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)-\psi ^{\left( 0 \right)}\left( 1 \right) \right)^{2} \right)\beta \left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)$

$=\frac{2\pi }{s^{3}}\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)=\frac{2\pi }{s^{3}}\psi ^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)=\frac{\pi ^{3}}{s^{3}}$

Finally
$\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}Li_{2}\left( -x \right)dx}=-\frac{\pi ^{2}}{12}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}dx}-\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{1+x^{s}}\ln ^{2}xdx}$

$=-\frac{\pi ^{3}}{12s}-\frac{\pi ^{3}}{4s^{3}}=-\frac{\pi ^{3}}{4s}\left( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{s^{2}} \right)$

Comment: To make your question clear: You are asking if one can provide a proof with less computation. Correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a shortcut, indeed. By exploiting $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\left[\,f(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]\,dx $ the original integral boils down to:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{s/2-1}}{x^s+1}\left[\text{Li}_2(-x)+\text{Li}_{2}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]\,dx=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{s/2-1}}{x^s+1}\left[\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(x)\right]\,dx $$
which is equivalent to:
$$ I(s)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s/2-1}}{x^s+1}\left[\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(x)\right]\,dx. $$
Assuming $s$ has a positive real part and enforcing the substitution $x=z^{2/s}$,
$$ I(s)=-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\pi^2}{3s}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z^2+1}+\frac{4}{s^3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2+1}\,dz\right].$$
The claim simply follows from $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2+1}\,dz=\frac{\pi^3}{8}.$